# Discord.py | Unknown problem with mute command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So, I have this timed mute command and it isn't working like its giving no errors and doesn't work
here is the code:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member=None, time:int=None, reason=None):
    muted_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if not muted_role:
      muted_role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Muted")
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
         await ctx.channel.send("You cannot mute yourself :angry:")
         return
    if time == None:
      return await ctx.channel.send("You have to write the time for which you want to mute the mentioned user!")
      if reason == None:
        reason = "For being a jerk."
    pos1 = ctx.guild.roles.index(ctx.author.top_role)
    pos2 = ctx.guild.roles.index(member.top_role)
    if pos1 == pos2:
        return await ctx.send("Both of you have the same power so I can not mute this user for you!")
    if pos1 < pos2:
        return await ctx.send("This person has more power than you so I can not mute him/her for you!")


    time_convert = {"s":1, "m":60, "h":3600,"d":86400}
    tempmute = int(time[:-1]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
    await member.add_roles(muted_role)
    await ctx.send(f'{member} has been muted for {time}. Reason: {reason}.')
    await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
    await member.remove_roles(muted_role)
```

Comment: Does it gives the "Muted" role at least? If it does, you should manually configure permissions for "Muted" role for every single channel.

Comment: nope it doesnt even do that and gives no reply and no errors

Comment: but if i dont put in an argument like time or member then it gives that reply that i have set so that means that the code works to that point

Comment: Try to create mute function without using ext_commands. I mean with on_message() function, and see if it works.

Comment: alright i'll try

Comment: could u tell me how would i do that cus i'm getting confused with all the required arguments and stuff like how would i put them

Comment: Then let me write a sample on_message() function for you as an answer.

Comment: alright sure write it

Comment: Sorry but I'm having a similar problem, bot is not adding the role. I can't help with that.

Comment: alright np thanks for trying tho